# Are PandasDataframe to_csv in pyspark stored in spark driver memory?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am running pyspark in a Yarn cluster .Just a question that comes to my mind. When you use Pandas Dataframes in a spark cluster, you are using spark driver’s memory. If you save that pandas df into a csv with to_csv() method, is this csv output stored permanently in drivers memory or maybe this file is deleted when closing the spark session?

Answer (score 1):

Pyspark is distributed processing framework while pandas runs the code on single node so as soon as you convert your pyspark dataframe to pandas dataframe it is executed on the driver itself.

And when you execute pandas_df.to_csv it is not stored on memory it is stored on the path provided by you on disk. So driver memory doesn't contain it.